# How to find only urls in huge text block in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have some description Like 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://example.com Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet www.example.com/query/exm/ etc'

Now form these text I want to find urls like http://example.com and www.example.com/query/exm/

Please help me how to do?

Comment: Do you have a list of urls, maybe of their dns names / ip addresses, or do you need a generic identification ? Will your text blocks fit in a plsql varchar2 variable (ie. being smaller than 32767 chars) ? Do you want to indicate the presence of an url, count occurrences, extract them, replace them,or do something different ?

Comment: Thanks  collapsar for your reply.Actually I need to find urls in text description once if I found that I want to make them as hyperlink.I want identify urls and make them hyperlink

Comment: Yes In your terms it shoud be generic identification

Comment: When you say, you want to 'make hyperlinks', do you mean that you want to add a html anchor element ? If so, is your original data plain text or may it already contain html markup?

Comment: Yes,it already contain html markup

Comment: In html markup only I have description containing URLs.I want to find those urls and make them hyperlinks

Comment: Handling this situation properly will require some effort, since you need to distinguish between plain text portions (where you want to replace urls identified as such) and html syntax elements (attribute values, comments, processing instructions), where you don't. Do you have any more info about the nature of markup that may occur in the original text? In particular, can you guarantee that your markup is well-formed (ie `<`,`>` being properly escaped)?

Comment: Currently I got some solution like 
v_val := REGEXP_SUBSTR('description containing urls',
   'https://([[:alnum:]]+\.?){3,4}/[[:alnum:]]+?') ;
but its not full solution some urls parameters is coming out of anchor tag

Comment: yes markup is well formed

Comment: A purely regex-based approach will fail, since urls may occur inside attribute values, where you do not want to substitute. I see no way tosafely define the admissible contexts by regex patterns (even more so with the limited expressiveness of oracle regexen).

Comment: Also note that in your example,  not every link has the leading protocol specifier (eg.`https://`) as the regex you sent presupposes.

Comment: Actually Description and urls present in <p></p> tags

Comment: Yes I may have https:// protocol also,its not possible to fix?

Comment: Actually I am totally new to plsql Sorry may be I am troubling u lot

Answer (score 0):

***Warning***

The solution is a heuristical one. Basically it tries to get around properly parsing grammatical content. While this approach might work most of the time, it is bound to fail sooner or later on complex inputs. However, as an ad hoc solution it might still be sufficient.

In short: **What follows does not represent recommended practice. It is not universally applicable.**

***Description***

The following function maps a string, possibly enriched with html markup, to another string where all strings recognized as urls have been replaced with a html anchor element.

The transformation is based on regular expressions:

- to distinguish between plain text and html elements. Conceptually, the original data is regarded as an alternating stream of html syntax elements and plain text. Plain text segments may be empty. Absence of any html markup is supported.
- to detect an url. Every string that occurs in a plain text segment and that meets the requirements listed below is considered an url. This pattern is  heuristical:

  - a url is delimited by at least one space or horizontal tab character.
  - a url contains a sequence of alphanumeric characters plus the underscore and the dot. Note that this is more restrictive than the definition in the official rfc.
  - The above sequence must contain at least 1 dot.
  - The above sequence may be followed by additional material on which no restriction is imposed, except that it mustn't contain one of the possible url delimiter symbols (space or tab character).
  - a url optionally starts with a protocol specifier, which must be either `http://` or `https://`.

***Known shortcomings***

- If the original string contains html anchors whose textual content contains a url in the sense of above, this url will be transformed.
- The maximum size of content is 32767 (after substitution). The code can be adapted to work with clobs however.

***Code***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION augment_with_links ( original IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    TYPE t_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    s_html  VARCHAR2(32767);
    a_parts t_array;
    a_seps  t_array;

    PROCEDURE split_by_regex ( str IN VARCHAR2, pattern in VARCHAR2, parts OUT NOCOPY t_array, seps OUT NOCOPY  t_array ) IS
        n_offset       SIMPLE_INTEGER := 1;
        n_next_start   SIMPLE_INTEGER := 0;
        n_next_end     SIMPLE_INTEGER := 0;
        n_part         SIMPLE_INTEGER := 1;
    --
    BEGIN
       IF LENGTH(str) > 0 THEN
          LOOP
             n_next_start := REGEXP_INSTR(str, pattern, n_offset, 1, 0); 
             IF n_next_start = 0 THEN
                IF n_part = 1 THEN
                   parts(1) := str;
                ELSE
                   parts(n_part) := SUBSTR(str, n_offset);
                END IF;
                RETURN;
             ELSE
                n_next_end := REGEXP_INSTR(str, pattern, n_next_start, 1, 1);
                parts(n_part) := SUBSTR(str, n_offset, n_next_start - n_offset);
                seps(n_part)  := SUBSTR(str, n_next_start, n_next_end - n_next_start);
                n_offset := n_next_end;
                n_part   := n_part + 1;
             END IF;
          END LOOP;
       END IF;
       RETURN;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
          parts(n_part) := '';
          seps(n_part)  := '';
    END split_by_regex;
BEGIN
    split_by_regex ( original, '<[^>]+>', a_parts, a_seps );
    FOR i IN 1 .. a_parts.COUNT LOOP
        IF a_parts(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
            s_html := s_html ||
                REGEXP_REPLACE ( 
                      a_parts(i)
                    , '(^|[ '||CHR(9)||'])((http[s]?://)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+([^ '||CHR(9)||'])*)([ '||CHR(9)||']|$)'
                    , '\1<a href="http://\2">\2</a>\6'
                );
        END IF;

        IF a_seps.COUNT >= i THEN
            IF a_seps(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
                s_html := s_html || a_seps(i);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE ( s_html, 'href="http://(http[s]?://)', 'href="\1' );
END augment_with_links;
/
show err
```

The code has been tested with the following statements:

```
SELECT augment_with_links ( 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://example.com Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet www.example.com/query/exm/ etc' ) FROM DUAL;
SELECT augment_with_links ( 'Lorem <span style="color:green">ipsum dolor sit</span> amet, http://example.com Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet www.example.com/query/exm/ etc' ) FROM DUAL;
SELECT augment_with_links ( 'Lorem <span style="color:green"><a href="http://predefined.example.com">Predefined Link</a>ipsum dolor sit</span> amet, http://example.com Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet www.example.com/query/exm/ etc' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Than yo so much collapsar for your valuable effort.much appreciated
I will check this solution